# Using Airbnb EsLint Configuration with Hound CI

Tags: eslint, lint, eslint-config-airbnb

I want to use Hound CI's automated github commenting but have the javascript configured to air bnb's eslint guide (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb).  I seem to be failing at getting the configuration of Hound to pick up the eslint rules provided in that package.

If somebody has steps or a demo app that has this working, I'd really appreciate the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable eslint by adding the following to your hound.yml

```
eslint:
  enabled: true
```

Source: https://houndci.com/configuration#eslint

Please be advised this is still in beta.